# Como se hace para que muestre lo siguiente en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tengo una duda lo que tengo que mostrar es lo siguiente 
en el caso de que cte fuese 1 tiene que listar a la par de cte lo siguiente (SIN DATOS,TITULAR,INTERINO,SUPLENTE,PROV. C/RETER,PROVISORIO A TERMINO) 
y en el caso de ser cte 2 Mostrar PERMANENTE,CONTRATADO,TEMPORARIO,PROVISORIO) 
Como puedo hacerlo ya que la sentencia que utilizo no realiza eso

```
select top (10) t.tab_sit_rev_id as id,t.tab_sit_rev_desc as descripcion,t.cte_tipo_sit_rev as cte,sitrevs = (select STUFF((select ', '+ ta.tab_sit_rev_desc
                    from TAB_SIT_REVISTA_CARACTER ta
                    for xml path('')),1,1,''))from TAB_SIT_REVISTA_CARACTER t
```

Comment: Como seria la aplicación de CASE en este caso en que parte de la sentencia se colocaría ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una expresión `CASE`:

```
SELECT TOP(10) col1, 
               col2, 
               CASE cte_tipo_sit_rev
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'SIN DATOS,TITULAR,INTERINO,SUPLENTE,PROV. C/RETER,PROVISORIO A TERMINO'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'PERMANENTE,CONTRATADO,TEMPORARIO,PROVISORIO'
               END 
FROM ....
```

Puesto en tu código sería:

```
SELECT TOP (10) t.tab_sit_rev_id   AS id, 
                t.tab_sit_rev_desc AS descripcion, 
                t.cte_tipo_sit_rev AS cte, 
                CASE t.cte_tipo_sit_rev 
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'SIN DATOS,TITULAR,INTERINO,SUPLENTE,PROV. C/RETER,PROVISORIO A TERMINO'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'PERMANENTE,CONTRATADO,TEMPORARIO,PROVISORIO'
                END,
                sitrevs = (SELECT Stuff((SELECT ', ' + ta.tab_sit_rev_desc 
                                         FROM   tab_sit_revista_caracter ta 
                                         FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')) 
FROM   tab_sit_revista_caracter t;
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto estuve probando en la consulta pero no me funciona, lo mas seguro es que este la este escribiendo mal, podría ser si no es mucha molestia mostrarme como seria colando el CASE dentro de la consulta que publique y que resultados te muestran recordar que tengo que mostrar esos datos en la columna sitrevs

Comment: @pj2016 no lo hice sobre tu consulta porque posteaste una imagen, y no voy a darme el trabajo de transcribir el código. Si agregas el código **en texto** en tu pregunta, entonces podría hacerlo

Comment: Ok

Este es el codigo 

select top (10) t.tab_sit_rev_id as id,t.tab_sit_rev_desc as descripcion,t.cte_tipo_sit_rev as cte,
sitrevs = (select STUFF((select ', '+ ta.tab_sit_rev_desc
      from TAB_SIT_REVISTA_CARACTER ta
      for xml path('')),1,1,''))
from TAB_SIT_REVISTA_CARACTER t

Comment: @pj2016 Edita la pregunta y añade ahí el código

Comment: Ahí la actualizace